# Select relation between two columns in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

[image: Sample]

I want select `Data3` on `Column2` relation values. 
`Column2.Data3` relation with `Column1.Data2_005`.
`Column1.Data2_005` contains `Column2.Data2`. 
`Column1.Data1_001` contains `Column2.Data1`.
If `column1` does not contain with `column2` end the loop.

And here is my Output.
[image]

Comment: Please explain properly. you question is not clear so far

Comment: @vivek nuna. I want what are the relationship avilable on given data based on column2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to look recursively in the table for `Column2` values that are contained in the previous `Column1` value. You can do this using a common table expression;

```
WITH cte(Column1, Column2) AS (
  SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM test t WHERE Column2='Data3'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.Column1, t.Column2 FROM test t 
  JOIN cte 
    ON CHARINDEX(t.column2, cte.Column1) > 0
)
SELECT * FROM cte;

>>>

Column1     Column2
Data2_005   Data3
Data1_001   Data2
GML1        Data1
```

The first select finds the base case (the row with `Column2` equal to `Data3`).

The second select joins with `cte` itself which in this case contains the previous row so you can match with the previous `Column1` value to find the next row.

Beware of loops (for example a row with `Data3_001` + `Data3` would fail the query)

Comment: Thanks a lot and its wroking fine but i got some recursion error on this query. "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion."

Answer (score 0):

other flavor:

```
create table #temp (column1 nvarchar(20), column2 nvarchar(20))
insert into #temp values
('GML1', 'Data1'), 
('Data1_001', 'Data2'), 
('Data2_005', 'Data3'), 
('GML2', 'Data10'),
('Data10_001', 'Data11'), 
('Data10_005', 'Data12')


;with cte
as
(
select column1, column2 from #temp where column2='Data3'
union all
select a.column1, a.column2 from #temp a join cte b on a.column2 = SUBSTRING(b.column1, 0, Len(b.column2)+1)
)
select * from cte order by column2
```